# Diferencia entre windows.h | stdafx.h

Tags: c++, c, vscode

### INCÓGNITA

trato de aprender como crear una `.DLL` *dynamic link library* el libro que leo no es actual, y en el indica como hacer una `.DLL` para windows 32 bits. Yo uso **VS 2017 PRO**, el libro está narrado con **VS 2013**.

en el libro <kbd>SC</kbd> comienza así

```
// Dll1.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include windows.h
```

y cuando trato de adaptarme a **VS 2017 PRO** mi proyecto es un `.DLL` *dynamic link library* **VACIO** por lo cual se ve de esta forma.

```
// Dll1.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
```

Cual es la diferencia entre estos dos **HEADERS** (cabeceras)

- windows.h
- stdafx.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cual es la diferencia entre estos dos **HEADERS** (cabeceras)
>
> - windows.h
> - stdafx.h

Todo. De hecho es como si preguntases la diferencia entre el manual de instrucciones de un coche y una barrita de cereales.

---

#### La cabecera [`"Windows.h"`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h)

> Contiene las declaraciones de todas las funciones de la biblioteca [Windows API](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API), todas las macros utilizadas por los programadores de aplicaciones para Windows, y todas las estructuras de datos utilizadas en gran cantidad de funciones y subsistemas.

A grandes rasgos, es la cabecera que se necesita para comunicar tu programa con el sistema operativo Windows.

#### La cabecera `"stdafx.h"`

Dado que la compilación de programas en lenguaje C++ y C es muy<sup>1</sup> lenta, algunos compiladores usan trucos para acelerar los tiempos de compilación, uno de estos trucos son las [cabeceras pre-compiladas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#Microsoft_Visual_C_and_C++):

> Una cabecera que es compilada a una forma intermedia que es más rápida de procesar por el compilador. El uso de cabeceras pre-compiladas puede reducir de manera significativa el tiempo de compilación, especialmente al aplicarse a cabeceras grandes o cabeceras que incluyen otras cabeceras.

A grandes rasgos, es la cabecera a la que van a parar todas las cabeceras que usas en tu programa para ser pre-compiladas.

---

1. MUY.

Comment: que es 1. MUY ?

Comment: @BlenderBlackened es un adverbio que antepuesto a otras palabras, indica grado alto de una propiedad. Las mayúsculas son para enfatizar, no para hacer que sea un acrónimo.

Comment: ajajaj ok :P, muchas gracias

Comment: entonces en mi diseño de solución me es mas conveniente incluir ambas cabeceras cor cuestiones de mejorar el poseso de compilación o stdafx.h ya anula Windows.h ? que me recomiendas hacer, poner ambas ? o escoger alguna de las 2, mi confusion viene porque desde que deje de usar vs 2013 muchas cosas cambiaron en vs 2017

Comment: `stdafx.h` no anula `Windows.h`, no tienen nada que ver la una con la otra. Yo personalmente no uso cabeceras pre-compiladas (`stdafx.h`) porque me suponen un engorro y no son portables (pero si vas a programar sólo para Windows, la portabilidad no será un problema). El IDE que estés usando (MSVC 2013 o 2017) no influye en el uso y misión de estas cabeceras, puedes usarlas a la vez, una u otra o ninguna.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias una vez mas, creo que ya voy comprendiendo mejor el tema, si, la dll que quiero diseñar solo es para windows, así que probare usando ambas en una solución y usando solo windos.h en otra para ver que sucede , solo por quitarme la curiosidad de que puede salir mal jajaja

Comment: Piensa que stdafx.h es como si lo hubieras creado tú. Lo hace el IDE por ti, pero puedes usarlo o no (desactivando en la configuración del proyecto), para todo el proyecto o para ficheros de código individuales. En él metes los includes de todo lo que tú no programas pero usas, como windows.h (seguramente el IDE te lo habrá metido en stdafx.h). Todos tus ficheros de código que incluyan el stdafx.h incluirán lo que tenga este dentro. Así si windows.h está dentro, podrás usar las definiciones de ese header en todos los sitios donde incluyas stdafx.h. Además, acelera la compilación.

Comment: It seems like an extensive topic, where can I see an example of this?